# How to do personal chat using socke.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm new to `node.js`. I tried `socket.io` as it emits message to all clients, but I don't know how to do personal chat using `socke.io`, without using **php**.

Comment: The socket.io doc page includes code for a sample chat app using node.js and browser.  That's where you should start.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I don't want to build a chat but a private messenger. I'm unable to find such things in socket.io doc.

Comment: I got solution..(i.e).io.to(socket.id).emit('message', 'for your eyes only');

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to explore the [Rooms and Namespaces](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/) section of socket.io documentation. It is designed for the exact use cases you are looking for.

> Socket.IO allows you to “namespace” your sockets, which essentially
>   means assigning different endpoints or paths.
>
> This is a useful feature to minimize the number of resources (TCP
>   connections) and at the same time separate concerns within your
>   application by introducing separation between communication channels.

About rooms:

> Within each namespace, you can also define arbitrary channels that sockets can join and leave.

So each conversation would be single channel with two subscribers. To ensure privacy you can use a unique token as channel identifier that is distributed to only the relevant parties.